# Set dot color based on where they are in Python turtle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
speed("fastest")


pendown()
goto(200, 0)
goto(200, 200)
goto(0, 200)
goto(0,0)
goto(200,200)

area_size = 800 
max_coord = area_size / 2

num_dots = 300 

setup(area_size, area_size)

for _ in range(num_dots):

    dots_pos_x = randint(-max_coord, max_coord)
    dots_pos_y = randint(-max_coord, max_coord)

    penup()
    goto(dots_pos_x, dots_pos_y)
    dot(4)
    pendown()


hideturtle()
done()
```

This code draws a square with a line splitting it into two equal triangles. How can i get the dots that land in one half of the square to turn red but turn blue when they land in the other half of the square. The dots that don't land in the square stay black.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the random module and generating first the x coordinate and then the y coordinate. If this is indeed your method, then run a check on each as you generate it to see if it's within the confines of your box. ie `if (x > 10) and (x < 20):` and `if (y > 15) and (y < 25):` If the statement is true then set a variable the_color to red, `else`, set it to blue

Comment: im talking about if i drew a square using the following commands, import turtle

turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(200)

print turtle

and when i generate for example 300 random dots, how would i get the ones that get into the square to change red? how would i define the square. sorry im a complete python noob

Comment: @user2673638 how are you "generating" 300 random dots and then drawing them? Where is the turtle starting? These are things that you should edit your question to include so that we can better help you. Can you post all of the relevant code you are using in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been a few years, below is a posible solution to this problem.  Note that I switched from `turtle.dot()` to `turtle.stamp()` which speeds up the execution by 2.5X:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

AREA_SIZE = 800
MAX_COORD = AREA_SIZE / 2
SQUARE_SIZE = 200
DOT_SIZE = 4
NUM_DOTS = 300
STAMP_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(AREA_SIZE, AREA_SIZE)

turtle = Turtle(shape="circle")
turtle.shapesize(DOT_SIZE / STAMP_SIZE)
turtle.speed("fastest")

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.left(45)
turtle.goto(SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE)
turtle.penup()

black, red, green = 0, 0, 0

for _ in range(NUM_DOTS):

    color = "black"

    x = randint(-MAX_COORD, MAX_COORD)
    y = randint(-MAX_COORD, MAX_COORD)

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    # color dot if it's in the square but not smack on any of the lines
    if 0 < x < SQUARE_SIZE and 0 < y < SQUARE_SIZE:
        if x < y:
            color = "green"  # easier to distinguish from black than blue
            green += 1
        elif y < x:
            color = "red"
            red += 1
        else black += 1  # it's on the line!
    else:
        black += 1  # it's not in the square

    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.hideturtle()

print("Black: {}\nRed: {}\nGreen: {}".format(black, red, green))

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note that I used green instead of blue as I was having too hard a time distinguishing the tiny blue dots from the tiny black dots!

OUTPUT

[image]

At the end it prints out a tally of how many dots of each color were printed:

```
> python3 test.py
Black: 279
Red: 5
Green: 16
>
```